# Countable stability of Hausdorff dimension

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can some one explain this property & the proof for me ? 
It goes like this:

If $F_1,F_2,....$ is a countable sequence of sets then $\dim_H \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i=\sup_{1 \leq i < \infty} \{\dim_HF_i\}$. Since $\dim_H \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i \geq \sup_{1 \leq i < \infty} \{\dim_HF_i\}$ from the monotonicity. For the other direction, if $s>\dim_HF_i$ for all $i$, then $H^s(F_i)=0$, so we have $H^s(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i)=0$. I know the first direction, but what about the second direction ?

Answer (score 3):

Let $(X_j)_{j \geq 0}$ be a family of subsets of $X$.

If $(U_i^j)_{i \in I}$ is a $\delta$-cover of $X_j$, then $(U_i^j)_{(i,j) \in I \times \mathbb{N}}$ is a $\delta$-cover of $\bigcup\limits_{j \geq 0} X_j$. Thus, $$H_{\delta}^s \left( \bigcup\limits_{j \geq 0} X_j \right) \leq \sum\limits_{j \geq 0} \sum\limits_{i \in I} |U_i^j|^s;$$ taking the minimum over the $\delta$-cover, we obtain $$H_{\delta}^s \left( \bigcup\limits_{j \geq 0}X_j \right) \leq \sum\limits_{j \geq 0} H_{\delta}^s(X_j);$$ when $\delta \to 0$, we get $\displaystyle H^s \left( \bigcup\limits_{j \geq 0} X_j \right) \leq \sum\limits_{j \geq 0} H^s(X_j)$.

Therefore, if for all $j \geq 0$, $H^s(X_j)=0$, we necessarily have $H^s \left( \bigcup\limits_{j \geq 0} X_j \right)=0$. We deduce that $\dim_H \left( \bigcup\limits_{j \geq 0} X_j \right) \leq \sup\limits_{j \geq 0} \dim_H(X_j)$.

Comment: I understand the idea of this proof but one step is unclear to me: why can you exchange sum and limes on the right side of the inequality? What I mean is why can you do this: 
$\lim_{\delta \to 0} \sum_{j} H_{\delta}^s(X_j)=\sum_{j} \lim_{\delta \to 0}  H_{\delta}^s(X_j)$

Comment: The very last step is the one that puzzled me in the proof in Falconer's  book, which (based on OP's choice of words) is clearly the inspiration for the question.  Seirios, I know it's been several years, but would you (or anyone else) be willing to explain why "We [can] deduce that ...."  Thanks.

Comment: I've posted a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827302/last-step-in-proof-of-countable-stability-of-hausdorff-dimension) about that last step.