# Last step in proof of countable stability of Hausdorff dimension

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fractals, hausdorff-measure, dimension-theory-analysis

In part of Kenneth Falconer's proof of the countable stability of Hausdorff dimension on p. 49, sect 3.2 of [Fractal Geometry](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Fractal+Geometry%3A+Mathematical+Foundations+and+Applications%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9781119942399), I understand him to say that
$$\dim_H \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i\leq \sup_{1\leq i\leq\infty}\{\dim_H F_i\}\;,$$
because when $s>\dim_H F_i$ for all $i$, ${\cal H}^s(F_i)=0$, and thus
$${\cal H}^s(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\cal H}^s(F_i) = 0\;.$$
Here $\dim_H$ is Hausdoff dimension, and ${\cal H}^s$ is $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

I understand everything after $s>\dim_H F_i$ above, but I'm confused about why ${\cal H}^s(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\cal H}^s(F_i) = 0$ implies $\dim_H \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i\leq \sup_{1\leq i\leq\infty}\{\dim_H F_i\}$.

I understand that Hausdorff dimension of a set $G$ is the Hausdorff measure for which ${\cal H}^s(G)$ is finite, such that for $s>\dim_H G$, the Hausdorff measure is $0$, and for $s<\dim_H G$, the Hausdorff measure is infinite.  I don't see why the fact that ${\cal H}^s(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i) \leq 0$ for an $s$ that is larger than the dimension implies the first inequality above, which concerns a $\sup$ for Hausdorff dimensions that are possibly greater than $0$.  I'm sure there must be something obvious that I'm not seeing. I've been thinking about it for a week and I'm still confused.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/772605/73467) gives a detailed proof of the part I already understand, but leaves my question unanswered.

Comment: Looking quickly at this (I'm in the middle of something else), I think one approach is to assume, for a later contradiction, that $\sup_{1\leq i\leq\infty}\{\dim_H F_i\} < \dim_H \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i.$ As a consequence of this **strict inequality**, it follows that you can sandwich a real number $s$ strictly between these two quantities, namely $\sup_{1\leq i\leq\infty}\{\dim_H F_i\} < s < \dim_H \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i,$ and I believe it's not difficult to get a contradiction from this. For instance, note that $\dim_H F_i < s$ for each $i,$ so $\dots$

Comment: Thanks @DaveL.Renfro.  Thinking about that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $\dim_H(F)=\inf\{s:\mathcal{H}^s(F)=0\}$. So,
$$
\begin{align*}
\sup\limits_i \dim_H(F_i) = s &\Rightarrow \sum\limits_i \mathcal{H}^{s+\epsilon}(F_i) = 0, \forall\epsilon>0\\
&\Rightarrow \mathcal{H}^{s+\epsilon}(\bigcup_i F_i) = 0, \forall\epsilon>0\\
&\Rightarrow \dim_H(\bigcup_i F_i)\leq s
\end{align*}
$$

where the first implication is due to monotonicity of $\mathcal{H}^s$ in $s$ (i.e., if all the $F_i$ are of dimension $s$ or lower, then, by definition and monotonicity, $\mathcal{H}^{s+\epsilon}$ is $0$ for all of them) and the 2nd implication is due to your quoted inequality. Technically, to get the last implication, let $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$.

(Sort of) intuitively: when the $F_i$ have dimension $s$ or lower, then for **all** bigger $t>s$, your inequality tells you that $\mathcal{H}^t$ of their union must already be $0$, so the dimension of that union (by definition as the **infimum**) can't exceed $s$.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this, feltshire.  I haven't yet had time to fully get my head back into Falconer and work through implications of your answer.  I'll vote/accept after I do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this 2nd part of the proof would fall into place if we pick
$\xi = \sup_{i=1,\infty} \dim_H(F_i)$.

Then, $\xi \ge \dim_H(F_i) = \inf \{s | \mathcal{H}^s (F_i) = 0\}, i=1,2,\dots$

Hence, $\mathcal{H}^{\xi}(F_i) = 0, i=1,2,\dots$. Now, assuming $\{F_i\}$ is (or can be partitioned into) a countable collection of disjoint Borel sets, then by Eq. (2.3) in Falconer's book,

$\mathcal{H}^{\xi}(F_i) = 0, i=1,2,\dots \implies \mathcal{H}^{\xi}(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i) = 0$

Therefore, $\inf \{s | \mathcal{H}^s (\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}F_i) = 0\} \le \xi$;

i.e., $\dim_H(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i) \le \xi = \sup_{i=1,\infty} \dim_H(F_i)$

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  This works for me.  I think there's a typo, though.  You wrote "Eq. (2.3)"; I think you meant (3.2) [p. 45], i.e. that ${\cal H}^s(F)=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}{\cal H}^s_\delta(F).$

Comment: The two answers so far are equally helpful; I'm accepting @feltshire's because it was first.