# Hausdorff Dimension of a set in R under the image of Continous map

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

In Falconer's book there is the following exercize:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(x) = x^2$ and let $F \subset \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\text{dim}f(F) = \text{dim}_H F$.

This function is not lipschitz continuous or alpha holder continuous so I can't use the theorems about related to these inequalities. Moreover, if I think about the usual cantor set dilated by 2 and then sent through this function -- the distances between some points are being compressed and the distance between other points are being expanded. So its not obvious to me that the fractal dimension remains constant.

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't recall what theorems there are for Lipschitz functions, but since your function $f$ is locally Lipschitz and [Hausdorff dimension plays well with countable unions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772140/countable-stability-of-hausdorff-dimension), you might still be able to apply such a theorem.